# How to differentiate between Amazon, Flipkart, Myntra, Paytm URL?

Tags: regex, url, regular-language, nsregularexpression

I want to differentiate between different URLs given by the user so that I can pass a particular URL to a particular function.

I want to use RegX for this job but I don't know how to do it perfectly.

Amazon URL-
https://www.amazon.in/Apple-iPhone-XR-64GB-Black/dp/B07JWV47JW?

Flipkart URL-
https://www.flipkart.com/dell-vostro-15-3000-core-i5-8th-gen-8-gb-1-tb-hdd-windows-10-home-2-gb-graphics-3580-laptop/p/itmfghfezgzbk6hz?

Myntra URL-
https://www.myntra.com/tights/hrx-by-hrithik-roshan/hrx-by-hrithik-roshan-women-blue-printed-rapid-dry-seamless-running-tights/8475747/buy

Answer (score 0):

If those URLs are all you're looking for, you can use `www\.(\w+?)\.(?:com|in)` to capture the "interior" of the URL. The regex looks for `www.`, captures one or more word characters, and then ends by looking for either `.com` or `.in`.

Depending on the language you're using, you can then take that captured string and do things with it.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/XgUM73/2)